# How to check if circles intersect each other?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime-error

This is my test class,

```
public class Shape2DTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
GeometricObject2D geoObject1 = new ComparableCircle2D(0, 5, 2); 
GeometricObject2D geoObject3 = new ComparableCircle2D(0, 0, 2);
System.out.println("geoObject1 overlaps geoObject3: "
                + geoObject1.intersect(geoObject3));
}
}
```

This is my circle class,

```
 public class ComparableCircle2D extends GeometricObject2D<ComparableCircle2D> {

            public double x, y;
            public double radius;

            ComparableCircle2D() {
                super();
                this.radius = 1.0;
            }

            ComparableCircle2D(double radius) {
                super();
                this.radius = Math.abs(radius);
            }

            ComparableCircle2D(double x, double y, double radius) {
                super(x, y);
                this.radius = Math.abs(radius);
            }

            public double getArea() {
                return Math.PI * getRadius() * getRadius();
            }

            public double getPerimeter() {
                return 2 * Math.PI * getRadius();
            }

            public void setRadius(double setRadius) {
                this.radius = Math.abs(setRadius);
            }

            public double getRadius() {
                return radius;
            }
            public double getX() {
                    return x;
            }

            public void setX(double x) {
                    this.x = x;
            }

            public double getY() {
                    return y;
            }

            public void setY(double y) {
                    this.y = y;
            }

           @Override
            public boolean intersect(GeometricObject2D g) {
                    ComparableCircle2D other = (ComparableCircle2D) g;
                    double dx = other.x - getX();
                    double dy = other.y - getY();
                    double radi = other.radius + getRadius();
                    return (dx * dx + dy * dy < radi * radi);
            }

            }
        }
```

this is my superclass,

```
public abstract class GeometricObject2D<T extends GeometricObject2D> implements
        Comparable<GeometricObject2D> {
    public double x, y;

    GeometricObject2D() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    GeometricObject2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public abstract double getArea();

    public abstract double getPerimeter();

    public abstract boolean intersect(GeometricObject2D g);

    @Override
    public int compareTo(GeometricObject2D o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want to find out possibility of intersecting two circles but there is an error in my code that I didn't realize.

For example I create two circle object **coordinates-1(0,0)** , **radius-1=2** and **coordinates-2(0,5)** ,**radius-2=2**. That above method must return false but returns true. I didn't find error.

```
System.out.println("geoObject1 intersects geoObject3: "
                + geoObject1.intersect(geoObject3));
```

prints `geoObject1 intersects geoObject3: true`

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: There is no debugging. I tried.@OliverCharlesworth

Comment: You tried what? Please make a [mcve]. It is impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: `"There is no debugging"`?? makes no sense. If you've not debugged yet, you will want to do it now -- find out what state your program is when it is misbehaving. Only you can do this at this point (without your posting a valid [mcve]).

Comment: You all didn't look at my tag and didn't read question exactly. That question is just algorithm question. Where is my mistake? I just asked it.@Tunaki,@Hovercraft Full Of Eels 2

Comment: The intersect method you wrote is ugly, but correct.  There must be something wrong in code you didn't post

Comment: @Twilight you mistake is it is likely to be; the values are not what you think they are. This is where debugging your code can show this.

Comment: `"You all didn't look at my tag and didn't read question exactly"` -- Perhaps  you haven't yet posted an adequate and *complete* question. Please consider this, then debug, then post a valid [mcve] if still stuck.

Comment: @Twilight In this case, a [mcve] would include the least amount of `ComparableCircle2D` and `GeometricObject2D` so that this compiles and we can get the print statement that you're getting.

Comment: Your `ComparableCircle2D` class has too many `}`. Please use your editor and indent your code properly to avoid such mistakes (most editors have tools which can do it automatically for you, like in Eclipse you could use `Ctrl+I` or `Ctrl+Shift+F`).

Comment: @PeterLawrey Quoted you in my answer. You were spot on.

Comment: Finally, you've posted enough information to allow folks to answer the question correctly. Do you see now why we were pressing you to debug your code? This is essential to do before coming here, else you often end up showing us the wrong code (as you've found out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Pshemo said, your code (now that you've shown it) has an extra `}` at the end that shouldn't be there.

How, if we paste all that code into [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/DCslF6), and run it, we confirm your error.

If we then **DEBUG** the code by adding a single `print` statement, we see:

```
dx=0.0, dy=0.0, radi=4.0
```

Hmmm, why is `dy = 0` when it should be `5`?

Answer: Because you added *another* set of `x` and `y` fields to your subclass, that is *hiding* the fields from the base class!!!!

Simple debugging would have shown you this yourself. This is what @PeterLawrey was talking about in his comment:

> you mistake is it is likely to be; the values are not what you think they are. This is where debugging your code can show this.

Of course, if you had used a good IDE, you wouldn't even need to debug, because the **IDE would have *warned* you about the field hiding**.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than Math.pow(x, 2) it is more efficient to do x * x, and instead of using Math.sqrt you can square the sum of the radii.

```
public boolean intersect(GeometricObject2D g) {
    ComparableCircle2D other = (ComparableCircle2D) g;
    double dx = other.x - x;  // e.g. 0 - 0
    double dy = other.y - y;  // e.g. 5 - 0
    double radii = other.radius + radius; // e.g. 2 + 2
    return dx * dx + dy * dy < radii * radii ; // e.g. 0 + 25 < 16 is false.
}
```

Comment: But while this is true, these suggestions are almost certainly not going to solve his problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I suspect that making the code simple and easier to understand the OP might come to the conclusion the values are not what he/she thinks they are. Also using more variables can aid debugging.

Comment: Matter of definition, but shouldn't that be `<=`? See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Intersection.html: *The intersection of two sets `A` and `B` is the set of elements common to `A` and `B`.* The single point where two circles meet is still an intersection point.

Comment: @Andreas according to that definition of circle the code is incorrect regardless of whether `<=` is used or `<`

Comment: @fabian Since it hasn't been stated anywhere, I assume you're referring to the case of one circle being entirely inside the other?

Answer (score 0):

You never assign the fields `x` and `y`. Therefore `dx` = `dy` = 0.

You have to either assign the field's values or use the fields in the superclass (but you shouldn't have fields with the same information in the same object, so remove the fields created in `ComparableCircle2D`).

Also if your circle is defined as contour, not as area, then the test for intercepting circles is incorrect. Consider the case where 2 circles with the same center have different radii: `dx² + dy² = 0 < dr²`, but the contours don't intersect; only the areas inside the circles overlap.